# Issue with auto sizing in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, autolayout

In my now playing view controller I have have a huge problem with the way labels/ buttons and images are being auto sized. I have tried every possible combination in the autosizing options, yet I still end up with the following result on my iPhone 5:

[image]

And the following result on an iPhone 4:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this that i am not aware of ? This is and old project and I am not getting the same options I would in newer projects i.e: 
[image]

So unfortunately this is what I have been working with in my inspector.: 
[image]

Any suggestions / idea  on how can I go about fixing these issues?

Update: [image]

Comment: someone is making a christmas music app.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato **updating a current one =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't it work if you just put your image to "Aspect Fit" with the autosizing properties you have the screenshot of? You don't need any additional views to accomplish this. I tried it on a test project it works.

Oh, and for the views for the title you need remove the top anchor and vertical streching.

To clarify this:

[image: Four inches]
[image: Three and a half inches]

**Update:**
Here's the graphic for the title autosizing properties:

[image]

Comment: You still need to remove the top anchor and vertical stretching for the title label. Did you do that? Basically the label is anchored to the bottom, left and right without any stretching.

Comment: Don't remove all the anchors. See the image I added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

Add those controls as a sub view of a secondary view. Set AutoResizingWidth property for the view. Set AutoResizingFlexibleLeftMargin for the first button. Remove all resizing for the middle one and set AutoResizingFlexibleRightMargin for the third one. Now try how it works. Remove the autoLayout propeties.

Best Regards